# Re-using the same StatefulWidget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to have re-use the same StatefulWidget in multiple different pages in Flutter. In the example below I want to MyGoogleMap to not be rebuild for each page. When I navigate to the second page using a TabBar it uses another new build of MyGoogleMap. I've tried using a global key and the same instance loads but only for a few seconds before I get the error that the same key is used twice.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

const double CAMERA_TILT = 0;
const double CAMERA_BEARING = 0;
const LatLng SOURCE_LOCATION = LatLng(42.747932, -71.167889);
const LatLng DEST_LOCATION = LatLng(37.422, -122.084);

class MyGoogleMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyGoogleMap({Key key}) : super(key: key);  // NEW CONSTRUCTOR

  @override
  State<MyGoogleMap> createState() => MyGoogleMapState();
}

class MyGoogleMapState extends State<MyGoogleMap> {

  double CAMERA_ZOOM = 16;
  CameraPosition initialCameraPosition;

  //Map controller
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  GoogleMapController controller;

  //Markers
  Set<Marker> _markers = Set<Marker>();

  Set<Polyline> _polylines = Set<Polyline>();

  // the user's initial location and current location
  LocationData currentLocation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
        zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
        tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
        bearing: CAMERA_BEARING,
        target: SOURCE_LOCATION);
    if (currentLocation != null) {
      initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
          zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
          tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
          bearing: CAMERA_BEARING);
    }
    return Container(
      height: 400,
      child: GoogleMap(
          mapToolbarEnabled: false,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          compassEnabled: true,
          tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
          markers: _markers,
          polylines: _polylines,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            //Change this to change styles
            // controller.setMapStyle(Utils.DarkStyle);
            _controller.complete(controller);
          })
    );
  }

}
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      extendBody: true,
      body: Container(
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 100,
          width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
          decoration: (selectedNavigationIndex == 3
              ? backgrounds.dark
              : backgrounds.normal),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            TopBar(),
            IndexedStack(
              children: <Widget>[
                MyGoogleMap(),
                MyGoogleMap(),
              ],
              index: selectedNavigationIndex,
            ),
            BottomBar(
                this.selectedNavigationIndexCallback, selectedNavigationIndex),
          ])),
    );
  }
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      extendBody: true,
      body: Container(
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 100,
          width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
          decoration: (selectedNavigationIndex == 3
              ? backgrounds.dark
              : backgrounds.normal),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            TopBar(),
            IndexedStack(
              children: <Widget>[
                MyGoogleMap(key: _MyGoogleMapState),
                MyGoogleMap(key: _MyGoogleMapState),
              ],
              index: selectedNavigationIndex,
            ),
            BottomBar(
                this.selectedNavigationIndexCallback, selectedNavigationIndex),
          ])),
    );
  }
```

Comment: There is most definitely a better way, but if you can't find anything, you could probably use Provider or GetIt and get the same widget that way, although providing the state of the widget instead of the actual widget would be far better.

Comment: Hi, perhaps its possible to provide me with some sample code. How can I pass the state of the widget to another widget?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62542531/10003008)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data/state across different routes (if I read the question correctly), see https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data. However, if you want the same state in different parts of the same widget tree, [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) is often the go-to method. I tend to prefer [`GetIt`](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) due to its similarities to dependency injection, but if you don't know what that means, stick with provider.